# Assigning a variable the exit status of `wait` command from a function

Tags: bash, function, shell, return-value, pid

I have a `function` that `wait`s for the given `pids`:

```
waitpid() { 
  wait "$@";
}
```

I can `wait` for `job`s this way:

```
sleep 5 &
spid=$!
waitpid $spid
echo $?
0
```

It works. However, I want to capture the `output` of the `function` in a variable:

```
sleep 5 &
spid=$!
spid_status=$(waitpid $spid)
echo $?
255
[1]+  Done                    sleep 5
```

This does not work, as `$()` starts a new `subshell`, and `wait` is not able to wait for shells that aren't children of its own.

Is there a workaround to that? I would like to have a function that `wait`s for `subshell`s to finish and `return`s all the exit status like this:

```
waitpids() { 
  local pids_status
  for pid in "$@"; do
    wait "$pid";
    pids_status+=($?)
  done
  echo "$pids_status[@]}"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid creating a subshell you'd have to use a redirect instead. The easiest is probably to create a temporary file to hold the data:

```
trap 'rm -f "$stdout"' EXIT # Optional
stdout="$(mktemp)"
waitpid > "$stdout"
spid_status=$?
```

Comment: Can you explain what the first line does? Will temp file "$stdout" be cancelled at the end of the job?

Comment: It will be deleted. This is useful if all the handling of this file happens within the same script, and you don't want to run out of disk space.